# Audio jack converter for iPhones

Tags: iphone

I purchased a set of studio headphones from Audio Technica. Turns out, the pin is 3.5 mm and is too big for my iPhone 5. Is there some sort of adapter that I can buy that will convert the pin to the one for an iPhone? (Links to the suitable product at RadioShack would be appreciated :))

Comment: Shopping and buying recommendations are shunned on this site. That said, go type "iphone to 3.5mm adapter" into google.

Comment: The iPhone headphone jack *is* a 3.5 mm jack. I think you'll need to elaborate on your problem -- is that the headphones you purchases have a larger than 3.5 mm plug or that they have a 3.5 mm plug but it just won't sit in the jack on the phone because of a case or what not?

Comment: Oops :) I didn't know that. Thank you :). It was the plug used for studio appliances and I need to use it for my iPhone 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iPhone jack is 3.5mm.

You probably have the 1/4 inch (6.3mm) and that is why it does not fit.

When looking for a adapter make sure it has 3 black rings and not 2. That is the iPhone required plug.